# Allow email address with a dot OR hyphen in the domain (HTML)

Tags: html, forms, email-validation, salesforce-marketing-cloud

I created a form using html. I have an email address field in which i'm allowing domains containing a dot. However i can still have domains with a hyphen, a kind of "user@my-domain.com" It's probably an easy edit in my code but i still can't find where and what i should add.

```
Here is my code :

 <div class="srf-field_wrapper">
                    <label for="emailAddress">E-mail*</label>
                    <input id="emailAddress" name="emailAddress" required="" type="text" placeholder="Ex: mon.adresse@email.fr*" pattern="[a-zA-Z0-9\.]+@[a-zA-Z0-9\.]+\.[a-z]+" oninvalid="setCustomValidity('Veuillez remplir ce champ obligatoire')" oninput="setCustomValidity('')">
                </div>
```

I know that "." means that we allow a dot in the domain. I want to express the fact that we can have a dot OR a hyphen in the domain.

Does someone can help me ?

Thank you for your help !

Comment: You should not _add_, you should _remove_ - remove that `pattern` attribute. Make the field type `email` instead - then you have validation of conformance to what is generally considered a valid email build-in already, and do not need to rely on your self-written expression (which as experience shows, is likely to fail in some case or other, sooner or later.)

Comment: yes exactly i agree but in my case i cannot change it, the email field has been created as a text field, there are regular api call, i don't want to take the risk to edit a field in this case however i 100% agree with you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
[a-zA-Z0-9\.]+@[a-zA-Z0-9]+[\.-]?[a-zA-Z0-9]+\.[a-z]+
```

What I did is remove the . from the allowed characters, and create two groups of the allowed characters instead of one.

Then I added `[\.-]?` between them. This makes an OR since 0 or 1 character only is allowed, between the dot and the hiphen.

That means there can be only 1 dot OR hiphen. in the domain.

Comment: Thank you very much, i'm gonna try it ! I don't really understand the difference between [a-zA-Z0-9\.] and [a-zA-Z0-9.] Still have another question : how to adapt it to allow email address like : fisrtname.name@my-domain.com ;

Comment: Actually, when inside [ ] \. or . are equivalent (I think!). The difference is when outside the [ ] because when inside the . means the dot character, while outside it means ANY non-space character. Using a \ escapes it and make it be a simple dot. I have edited the regex to be inside code blocks as the \ characters were not showing properly.

Comment: it helps me a lot ty!